# most efficient algorithm to choose a building to renew

Tags: algorithm

trying solve that next problem but im little struggling..
In a certain street there is a row of ≥2 old buildings. To improve the appearance of the street, it is necessary to renew the facade
of some of the buildings. Out of every two adjacent buildings, at least one of them needs to be renovated. Given an array of length 
indicating the cost of renewing each building. We have to choose which buildings to renew, so the total cost will be low as possible.
For example, if the given array is (50,30,40,60,10,30,10), then the optimal solution is to renew the
The buildings number 2,3,5,7 and the cost will be 30+40+10+10=90.

any help?

I tried to look on the first two numbers at the array:
if they are equal - I choose the second, because than I can ignore the third number at the array.

cant goo more than that...

Comment: If all test problems are as small as this sample you can brute force it using recursive backtracking and try all possible (legal) combinations for finding the most cost efficient one.

Comment: but im request to find the most efficient way..

Comment: Use dynamic programming. Find two solutions for one building and two solutions for two buildings, two solutions for three buildings, two solutions for four buildings, ... One solution is for the case, where the last building is renovated, the other solution, where either the last or the previous to last building is renovated. You have to use the last two results to calculate another entry. So to add the two solutions for a 6th building, consider 4 buildings with the 4th renovated and both 5-building solutions (with 5th renovated or not necessarily). Speed is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is a dynamic programming problem and we should be able to achieve a linear solution.

For each house, we can either renew it or not. But at a given house, there's not enough information available greedily to be sure whether we should renew it or not, so we have to try both options at each step.

If we choose to renew it, we incur its cost, but we have the freedom to ignore the costs of its adjacent neighbors.

If we choose not to renew it, we must accept the cost of renewing its adjacent neighbors.

The self-similarity required for DP shows up in the sense that once we've found the optimal cost for a given house `i`, we can solidify the minimal cost of the subarray to the left of `i` and we never need to visit it again.

In code, this means we'll have a DP cache that keeps track of the two choices (renovate or not) for each house `i`. For house `i`, if we renew it, we can take the lesser value of either renewing the house to its left or not. If we don't renew house `i`, we have no choice but to incur the cost of renewing the house to its left. Store both possibilities so `i+1` can make an informed decision.

```js
const minimizeRenewalCost = costs => {
  // dp[i][0] stores the min cost of renewing house i
  // dp[i][1] stores the min cost of not renewing house i
  const dp = [...Array(costs.length + 1)].map(e => [0, 0]);

  for (let i = 1; i <= costs.length; i++) {
    // renew i (pick min cost for either decision at i-1)
    dp[i][0] = Math.min(...dp[i-1]) + costs[i-1];

    // don't renew i (must renew i-1)
    dp[i][1] = dp[i-1][0];
  }

  return Math.min(...dp.at(-1));
};

const costs = [50, 30, 40, 60, 10, 30, 10];
console.log(minimizeRenewalCost(costs));
```

Comment: dont wanna sound rude.. but is it possible for u to write this code at java? cause i cant reallt understatnd javascript codes..

Comment: It's not rude, but if you understand the written algorithm the translation should be pretty clear. Treat it as pseudocode. The array initialization is effectively a zeroed out `int[costs.length + 1][2]` that looks like `{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, ...}` and the mins are taken across both elements of `dp[i]`. `dp.at(-1)` means the last element in the array, `dp[dp.length-1]`. Try writing it yourself to ensure you understand the logic.